# Node.js How to unit test multiple console logs with mocha and sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Function I am writing test for:

```
function showTime(isTime){
   if(isTime === true){
     console.log(boxen(chalk.inverse('It is time to start.')));
     console.log(boxen('Good Afternoon.'));
   else{
     console.log('It is not time.');
   }
}
```

This is what I have for the "it" statement with multiple console logs in the unit test:

```
it('Should log "It is time to start" and "Good Afternoon"', ()=>{
   let stub = sinon.stub(console, 'log');
   showTime(true);
   expect(stub).to.have.been.calledTwice;
   expect(stub.calledWith('It is time to start.')).to.be.true;
   expect(stub.calledWith('Good Afternoon.')).to.be.true

});
```

How can I properly check both of the console logs in the unit test? The unit test returns an AssertionError.

Update: test result error below:

```
AssertionError: expected false to be true
+ expected - actual

-false
+true
```

Comment: What's the `boxen`? What test result did you get? Show the test result

Comment: Test result has been added. Boxen is an npm package for styling the terminal into boxes.